Rust in Windows cannot build kafka dependencies
I am trying Rust for the first time, and wants to replicate my existing codes, which is a simple udp server to kafka producer .
My cargo file is
[dependencies]

dotenv = "0.15"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
uuid = { version = "1", features = ["v4"] }
chrono = "0.4"
kafka = "0.9"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"

Im using Eclipse in Windows and i always got error like

error: could not find native static library libssl, perhaps an -L flag is missing?

I even tried using librdkafka but got error like
error: failed to run custom build command for rdkafka-sys v4.7.0+2.3.0

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: D:\technical\workspace-rust\tutorial-project\target\debug\build\rdkafka-sys-f9b1f42210c729af\build-script-build (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  Cloning librdkafka

  --- stderr
  Building and linking librdkafka statically
  Running command: "cp -a librdkafka/. D:\technical\workspace-rust\tutorial-project\target\debug\build\rdkafka-sys-aea7f213b861767e\out" in dir: .
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\Bobby\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\rdkafka-sys-4.7.0+2.3.0\build.rs:38:19:
  Command failed with error: program not found
  note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

I already use MSYS2 to install necessary dependencies like open ssl,
Any advice?
Update:
I managed to solve this by using VPCKG on my laptop (windows);

"Windows is only supported when using the CMake build system via the cmake-build Cargo feature." from here
